# How do I query GCP log viewer and obtain json results in Python 3.x (like gcloud logging read)

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm building a tool to download GCP logs, save the logs to disk as single line json entries, then perform processing against those logs. The program needs to support both logs exported to cloud storage and logs currently in stackdriver (to partially support environments where exports to cloud storage hasn't been pre-configured). The cloud storage piece is done, but I'm having difficulty with downloading logs from stackdriver.

I would like to implement similar functionality to the `gcloud` function 'gcloud logging read' in Python. Yes, I could use `gcloud`, however I would like to build everything into the one tool.

I currently have this sample code to print the result of hits, however I can't get the full log entry in JSON format:

```
def downloadStackdriver():
    client = logging.Client()
    FILTER = "resource.type=project"
    for entry in client.list_entries(filter_=FILTER):
        a = (entry.payload.value)
        print(a)
```

How can I obtain full JSON output of matching logs like it works using `gcloud logging read`?

Based on other stackoverflow pages, I've attempted to use MessageToDict and MessageToJson, however I receive the error

> `"AttributeError: 'ProtobufEntry' object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`to_api_repr`](https://googleapis.dev/python/logging/latest/entries.html#google.cloud.logging.entries.LogEntry.to_api_repr) function on the `LogEntry` class from the [`google-cloud-logging`](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-logging/) package to do this:

```py
from google.cloud import logging

client = logging.Client()
logger = client.logger('log_name')

for entry in logger.list_entries():
    print(entry.to_api_repr())
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Dustin. Unfortunately I now get a different error:  
`TypeError: Can not find message descriptor by type_url: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog  `

I'm attempting to query for:
`logger = client.logger('cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity')  `

On another note, can I just query for all log names like in gcloud?

Comment: The argument to `logger` should be the name of the log you're trying to parse, I don' think `'cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity'` is valid here.

Comment: In the json field (viewed through Log Viewer and gcloud) the field is `"logName": "projects/windy-star-244817/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"`. If I enter any other combination of this name, I get an error that it was expecting `Expected the form projects/[PROJECT_ID]/logs/[ID]`

Comment: Seems like your most recent error is a library issue. The google.cloud.audit.AuditLog isn't in the commonly used protos and so doesn't return anything. There's an issue [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/5514) where they are working to fix this kind of thing.